# Symfony access parameters in parameters.yml from User entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I declared my roles with parameters.yml and I want to access them from my User entity for the getRoles function (from the UserInterface https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html#method_getRoles ).

```
role_global_admin: ROLE_GLOBAL_ADMIN
role_admin: ROLE_ADMIN
role_manager: ROLE_MANAGER
```

I wanted to access my parameters thanks to the service definition but I learned this is strictly forbidden in symfony (for the entities). Entities shouldn't have dependencies.

User.php

```
/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    if (true === $this->isGlobalAdminRole()) {
        return ['ROLE_GLOBAL_ADMIN'];
    }

    return null == $this->getSymfonyOrganigramRole() ? ['ROLE_MANAGER'] : [$this->getSymfonyOrganigramRole()];
}
```

I want to access the role_global_admin parameter for example and not its value directly. getRoles() is executed automatically during the connexion to give the user a role.

How can I achieve that, I want my roles to be centralized in the parameters file.

Thanks

Comment: Typically you would of course define roles in security.yaml.  Consider updating your question with a bit more info on how your parameters would be used.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your roles as constants in a separate file or in your entity and then use them in your entity, security.yml or any other yml file
[as mentioned here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files)

For example:

AppBundle\Utils\UserMetaData

```
class UserMetaData {
    const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
    const ROLE_USER  = 'ROLE_USER';
}
```

security.yml:

```
role_hierarchy:
    !php/const AppBundle\Utils\UserMetaData::ROLE_ADMIN: !php/const AppBundle\Utils\UserMetaData::ROLE_USER
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixes my problem partially for the security.yml but how should I access these constants in my User.php entity ?